# Need to fix PhoneGap code for reading file

Tags: cordova, brackets

I'm learning phonegap and nothing of anything because I forget how to program and I need help to read a .txt file and not that instead reads the file >>>

```
fileSystem.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, 
    function(fileEntry) {      
      // Get a File object representing the file,    
      // then use FileReader to read its contents.          
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {       
          var reader = new FileReader();         
          reader.onloadend = function(e) {       
             var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');  
             txtArea.value = this.result;  
             document.body.appendChild(txtArea);    
           };         
           reader.readAsText(file);   
       }, 
       errorHandler);  
    }, fail);       
console.log('Opened file system: ' + fileSystem.name); 
}
```

Comment: You may want to format your code in order to make it readable, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I tried but i think there is 1 more bracket i can't find a home for.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `}` on the last line. That seems to be the extra one.

You may also want to run the code through a "beautifier" like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to clean up the indentation. Sometimes this can actually help you understand the structure of the code better, because the hierarchy becomes more clear when everything's indented correctly.